# Time-budget tracking monitoring for PM and client

Tags: time-management, budget

As a PM I constantly struggle to shuffle information about used-up and remaining time budgets between customer and development team.

After receiving a job from the customer, and after detailing it with the customer, I ask the team for a more or less rough estimate of how long this will take.

I there an existing online (preferrably self-hosted) solution, which allows me to enter a new task, assign a time budget to this task, then have each team member book his or her time spent on the budget *and* allowing a customer "view only" access? Basically, a *water level meter* view for the remaining time on a task so I (and everyone else involved) can get an early warning system for tasks that are going over-time.

Edit 1:
I meant it to look kind of like this for the client / me, the PM:
[image]

Edit 2:
Sometimes, making a clean visualization for oneself is half the task done.
[This is the idea I just got making the above drawing, using the Google Charts javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/8c5p73L4/6/):
[image]

Now, if only I'd know enough javascript to make this more user friendly, eg. have a place for the team to enter a value, add it, then re-generate the chart. Sigh.

Comment: Tool recommendations are always out of scope for PM.se; see discussion on meta.  I believe there is a SW recommendations SE

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the Earned Value Management technique in order to keep updated the budget. See the wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earned_value_management) to understand why I refer to.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because of link rot. Can you include the relevant info from the link in your Answer?

Comment: Interesting, but I meant something like my [Edit1].

Comment: If you are using Scrum, the remaining time is based on the sprint duration. I mean, you are able to report which tasks (sprint backlog items) will be done and how many time will be used to do them (sprint duration - 2, 3 or 4 weeks). Forecasting is based on experience so, after ending some sprints (2, 3 or 4) and knowing the complexity of each task (product backlog item) based on the Scrum team rating you are able to determine how many time is needed to complete all of them. In addition, you are able to make a relationship between sprint/task cost and the money left.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SCRUM time assessment. I need to visualize remaining time budget in real billable hours towards the client.